# What does cin >> x evaluate to, on error?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this snippet:

```
int a;
while (cin >> a){/* do something */}
```

On running this code, suppose I enter a string. The loop is exited. But then, since the expression inside `while` ends in error, and it doesn't evaluate to a `bool` type (is this incorrect thinking?), how does the compiler know to exit the loop?

Comment: Yes,  but I'm considering the case when I enter a type that cannot be converted to `int`.

Comment: @tadman: It halts when I type in any string value. But why? The expression doesn't evaluate to false, since it ends in error.

Comment: [Documentation is your friend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) learn to read it frequently.

Comment: Yes it's wrong thinking. There's no concept in C++ of an expression *ending in error* (unless you mean an exception but that doesn't apply here). All that is happening is that `cin >> a` returns a value. That value can be converted to a boolean. And if `cin >> a` is successful that boolean value is true, otherwise it is false.

Comment: @TrainHeartnet But it does evaluate to false. Not sure where you got this `ends in error` concept from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cin >> x` returns `cin` to allow chaining.

And *in an boolean context*, `cin` evaluates to `true` if and only if the last operation was successful.

Long story short, the loop will end on the first end of file or error.

Answer (score 4):

`cin >> a` will always return a reference to `cin`.

The `std::basic_ios` base class has an `explicit operator bool()` that will be invoked when `cin` is "evaluated" in the condition of `if`, `while`, or `for`. When the operation fails, then `failbit` is set in the flags and the next time `cin` is converted to `bool`, the result is `false` because of the flag.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
cin >> a
```

You call the `basic_istream& operator>>( int& value );` and as you can see it returns `basic_istream&` so basically you have

```
while(cin)
```

and what that does is call

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

which will return true if the stream is not in an error state and false if it is in an eror state.  That is why the loop ends when there is an error.

Answer (score 2):

The condition in `while (cin >> a)` is not when `a != 0`, but when `std::cin` is valid.

`std::cin` becomes invalid if you input string instead of `int` or if stream ends for example.

Comment: My brain was inserting a false in *is not when a != 0*

Comment: @NathanOliver: *"is not when `a != 0`"* != *"is  when `a == 0`"* (but I continue to use `!=` so unsure what you will understand ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

The class `std::basic_ios`, the base class of the class `std::istream`, has the conversion operator

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

that returns true if the condition !fail().is true.

So if an error occurs in this statement

```
cin >> a
```

that returns the stream `std::cin` itself then it is contextually converted to the type bool with the value false and this loop

```
while (cin >> a){/* do something */}
```

does not execute its sub-statement.